# Java + MongoDB: Updating fields in amount of document

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to update at once fields in amount of document, I want to modify 
`"download=0"` where `"md5"` is in the list. When I run the code, it throws an exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
```

This is what I am doing:

```
//the list is an list of "md5"

List<BasicDBObject> updateCondition=new ArrayList< BasicDBObject>(list.size());  
for(int i = 0 ; i < list.size(); i++) {
    updateCondition.get(i).put("md5", list.get(i));
    DBObject updatedValue=new BasicDBObject();  
    updatedValue.put("download", 0);   
    DBObject updateSetValue=new BasicDBObject("$set",updatedValue);               
    vt_col.update(updateCondition.get(i), updateSetValue);  
}
```

The exception is occuring at :

```
 updateCondition.get(i).put("md5", list.get(i));
```

I want your help, thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug would help you a lot here, I can't say with a 100% accuracy, but I think you updateCondition maybe is empty.

You are trying to access updateCondition(0)... but you just create it with:

```
new ArrayList< BasicDBObject>(list.size());
```

The exception is throwing cause you don't have any objects in the list still, first you have to copy the list to the updateCondition list.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This answer is correct. To elaborate on why this happens: The constructor `ArrayList<T>(int initialCapacity)` does not create a list with `initialCapacity` entries, it creates an empty list with *reserved memory* for `initialCapacity` entries. Settng the reserved capacity of a collection is a pure performance-optimization but does not do anything regarding its behavior.